# SetSrc doen´t work

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
                    {                           
                        xtype: 'filefield',
                        x: 120,
                        y: 130,
                        width: 490,
                        //buttonOnly: true,
                        name: 'rutas',
                        itemId: 'rutas',
                        labelWidth: 90,                                                       
                        fieldLabel: 'Buscar Foto',  
                        listeners: {
                        'change': function (newVal) {
                            var file = newVal.fileInputEl.el.dom.files[0];
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            console.log(reader);
                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                            reader.onload = function (evt) {
                                var image = Ext.getCmp("imageid");
                                image.setSrc(evt.target.result);
                            }
                        }                
                    }
                    },

                    {
                        xtype: 'image',
                        x: 20,
                        y: 5,
                        itemId: 'imageid',
                        style: "border: 1px solid black",
                        minHeight: 90,
                        width: 65,
                        height: 'auto',
                        //src: 'img/trabajador.jpg'                            
                    },
```

Hello, I am using this code to preview an image after selected but I got this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setSrc' of undefined
>       at FileReader.reader.onload (FdatosTrabajador.js?_dc=1519840212167:405).

Any idea about how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Why do you tag `php`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Ext.getCmp(...) is undefined" in different function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083023/ext-getcmp-is-undefined-in-different-function)

Comment: this is your own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033539/changing-images-after-selecting-extjs) and you accepted you can see here as well what you doing wrong .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following line

```
var image = Ext.getCmp("imageid");
```

to

```
var image = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("[itemId=imageid]")[0];
```

**Example Fiddle:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ds8

Comment: After changing it, I am getting the same error.    .setSrc(evt.target.result); this is the part that says cannot read properly

Comment: Actually, I am using Ext JS 4.2.x., I do not know if this may be causing some problems since you did it in ExtJs 5.1.4. I am very new at coding so sorry if what I am saying is dumb